# Add a line in a UITableView till the end

Tags: ipad, uitableview

Hi i want to add a line in my UITableView just like the reminder apps red line. I tried adding it to my custom cell but then it only display in the cell which are used and not in all cell. I want a red image like below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To add UIView on tableView and set it`s Background Color with pattern Image whatever you want,then add such view on tableview. like below.

```
 lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 1,
 tblView.frame.size.height)];
 [lineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; //Change as per your req.
 lineView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
 [tblView addSubview:lineView];
```

But you face problem with this when you scroll up then at vertical bounce you have to manage height of this UIView. So you can implement this by ScrollViewDidScroll Delegate method, This method call cause UITableView is extends from UIScrollView.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    lineView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 1,    tblView.frame.size.height+scrollView.contentOffset.y); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UIView that has the size of the red stripe and place it over your UITableView where you want the red line to appear. Set it's backgroundColor to the color of the red line and make sure that `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO` to avoid interfering with the scolling of the UITableView.